# Finding unique rows from a SQL table while ignoring duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, database

we have a table like
Uid Cid 
1   100 
2   101
2   100 
3   101 
4   100 
4   101 
5   100
6   100
I want to count Uid where Cid = 101 but if the Uid in both (100,101)then it should count it 0. 
if i am writing the query like select count(*) from table where Cid = 101;
the result should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option, using aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT Uid
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Uid
    HAVING SUM(Cid = 101) > 0 AND SUM(Cid = 100) = 0
) t;
```

The `HAVING` clause asserts, for each `Uid`, that `Cid = 101` occurs at least once while `Cid = 100` does not occur.